# Moving text links closer together blocks some of the links

Tags: css, text, menu, hyperlink

I have a problem with my vertical menu.

I want my menu to look something like this ( http://svinehytten.dk/test/ ), but as you see "link2" gets in the way for clicking "link1".

I'm using `span`s to control the text, but I am open to any sugestions (I need it to validate perfectly as xhtml 1.0)

I have tried different ways to work around, even tried to make `div`s and turn them into links with javascript, but no matter what solution I try, the bigger text-pieces get in the way of the others.

Anyone has any ideas? is it possible to "send to back" or make the smaller link the primary one?

Comment: I would use images instead of text to avoid any weirdness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue my comment, I would use images like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/dnH4C/1/

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x40/000/fff"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x40/000/fff"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x40/000/fff"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x40/000/fff"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x40/000/fff"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x40/000/fff"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x40/000/fff"></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    width: 200px;
}

#menu img {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I wil prob end up using a rollover effect with some images. Though I would pref to keep the menu in text

Answer (score 0):

You can change the stack level on the `span`s.

Try this

```
#link1 {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 40pt;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative; /* ADD THIS */
    z-index: 1000;      /* ADD THIS */
}
```

Comment: the z-index makes it alot better, but does not fix it entirely. though with a lot of minor adjustments, it might work.